# icon issue in packageManager android

Tags: android

I can't get icon in properManner, I use `PackageManager`:

***Code example***

```
::List<PackageInfo> applications = getPackageManager().getInstalledPackages(0);
        for(PackageInfo info : applications){
            Drawable icon = info.applicationInfo.loadIcon(getBaseContext());
          }
```

> if I `print` icon to **LOGCAT** then I got result "icon is 9android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@4052d098
>   "
>   In main.xml file : `<ImageView android:id="@+id/imageView1" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:src="@drawable/icon"></ImageView>`
>
> I want just display icon to Imageview.

Comment: If youar getting result in log cat what's the problem then?

Comment: how can i display it to emulator?

Comment: Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)icon).getBitmap(); imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap); is this what you needed?

Comment: my plzr......I think I had earlier conversation regarding same issue am I right?

Comment: Oh thats great If my suggestions are useful for you and others, I am going to make it as an answer and you accept it so others might find it usefull

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to fecth bitmap from drawable and show in image view try below code

```
Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)icon).getBitmap(); 
imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```